# DataBinder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, databinder

i have this: ( useing Repeater but this bit long with all the fields problem is with this one)

```
<td valign="top">
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")%>
</td>
```

and :

```
        RentalCarBL.CarBL bl = new RentalCarBL.CarBL ();

        List<Car> cars = bl.GetAll();

        rpCars.DataSource = cars;

        rpCars.DataBind();
```

it works fine on all the fields of the class Car all but one the category is a class in it self
how do i make it show the the inner field of the class Category (lets say Category.name)?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")
```

returns an object type.

You should convert it to your category's class type first. such as

```
((YourCategoryClassName)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")).CategoryName
```

Comment: i tryed this but its not leting me use the class(YourCategoryClassName) in the aspx file and i cant add with using in this page so i dont know how to refernces it in ?  (should note that all my class obj are in class library )

Answer (score 0):

well it seems i had a problem with the DAL but after fixing it still had the problem 
 but it was sort of easy to fix sens he told me it return the object all i had to do is override the tostring of the Category :) and it workt fine